# How to upload a zip file to a URL with Ansible on Windows?

Tags: windows, ansible, windows-10

I am attempting to upload a zip file to a URL using Ansible on a Windows 10 machine. I'm currently trying something like the below:

```
    - name: Get zip file contents for upload
      slurp: 
        src: 'bundle.zip'
      register: zip_contents
      no_log: true
    - name: Upload ZIP
      ansible.windows.win_uri:
        url_method: "PUT"
        url: "my-url.com/bundle.zip"
        body: "{{ zip_contents['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

However, this results in a corrupt file being uploaded that is twice the expected size. I have tried to encode and decode a zip on my local to make sure this would work, and that seems fine. The above block works with other filetypes, like xml and json.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: According to ansible doc and github issues there's no limitation about working on zip file (and didn't find any example elsewhere). It seems like slurp doesn't like zip byte headers Dumb question : does your zip contains others zip files ? Also, your URL is hosted on a windows target that's right ?

Comment: Maybe this link may help you (same situation as yours) https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/2999

Answer (score 0):

Since I was trying to upload to Artifactory specifically, I found a workaround using the jfrog CLi:

```
    - name: Upload ZIP
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          jfrog rt u 'bundle.zip' 'my-repo/bundle.zip'
```

However I would love a more native Ansible solution if one exists.